# Jasypt | StrongPasswordEncryptor | Password not matching

Tags: java, jasypt

I am using Jasypt's [StrongPasswordEncryptor](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/util/password/StrongPasswordEncryptor.html) to encode user's password and for matching too.

I have created a util class to invoke its API :-

```
public class EncryptionUtil {

private static final StrongPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();

/**
 * Default private constructor.
 */
private EncryptionUtil() {
}

/**
 * Encrypts a string using {@link StrongPasswordEncryptor}
 * 
 * @param input
 *            Plain string
 * @return encrypted string.
 */
public static final String encyptString(final String input) {
    return passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword(input);
}

/**
 * @see StrongPasswordEncryptor#checkPassword(String, String)
 * @param plainPassword
 * @param encryptedPassword
 * @return boolean
 */
public static boolean checkPassword(String plainPassword, String encryptedPassword) {
    return passwordEncryptor
            .checkPassword(plainPassword, encryptedPassword);
}

}
```

Trying to test it using Junit runs perfectly fine:-

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String encryptedPassword = EncryptionUtil.encyptString("password");
    Assert.assertNotNull(encryptedPassword);
    Assert.assertTrue(EncryptionUtil.checkPassword("password",
            encryptedPassword));
}
```

I am storing user credentials in a SQL table. For testing/development environment I did a SQL insert after encrypting the password using the **EncryptionUtil** class.

**Problem:-**

The credential matching is failing  once its deployed/run to some other machine - when credential are fetched from database for matching.

After playing around a bit with the StrongPasswordEncryptor#encyptString, I found out that for the same plain password (say "password") the resultant encypted password is different when run multiple times.

i.e :-

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String encryptedPassword = EncryptionUtil.encyptString("password");
    System.out.println(encryptedPassword);
}
```

This would print different encrypted string on each run.
I am not an encryption expert, but I believe that the salt used by the StrongPasswordEncryptor is different in each run.

How do I fix this ?

I should be able insert encrypted user password in SQL table that passes the credential matching flow.

Comment: Seems good to me. Did you validate the test case without several restarts / deployments of the application?

Comment: The salt is prefixed to the output, I think. So your code should work fine. Perhaps your database storage/retrieval is to blame?

Comment: @Octopus No I didn't. Why the encrypted is different for each run ? Looking at the source code of StrongPasswordEncryptor, its default constructor (which will be called every time my application starts/restarts) has last statment as 'this.digester.initialize();'. I am not able to understand its purpose.

Comment: Yes, it need to get initialized every time of your application restart. How can you expect it to work without initialization?

Answer (score 1):

It would be different for every run of your test program since,`StrongPasswordEncryptor` will be created every time during start-up and attached to the class `EncryptionUtil` since it is marked as `static` and `final`. This means that SALT provided will also be new for every instance of `StrongPasswordEncryptor`

You need to read this, Directly from Documentation

When in a web application, Jasypt allows developers to avoid storing encryption passwords for PBE encryptors in files inside the webapp, specifying instead these passwords to the application through a web interface each time it is deployed.

- Special *Config classes: `org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.WebPBEConfig` and
  `org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.WebStringPBEConfig`, which when assigned to
  an encryptor, "mark" this encryptor as eligible for receiving its
  password via web.
- A context listener,
  `org.jasypt.web.pbeconfig.WebPBEInitializationContextListener` which
  will let us create our encryptors, set them their WebPBEConfig
  configs and register them somewhere in our application. This context
  listener will be unnecessary if we are using the Spring Framework.
- A filter, `org.jasypt.web.pbeconfig.WebPBEConfigFilter`, which will
  avoid any user to access the web application until the encryption
  passwords have been set by the admin.
- A servlet, `org.jasypt.web.pbeconfig.WebPBEConfigServlet`, which will
  show the authorised user a form with which he/she can set the
  encryption passwods for all encryptors with a WebPBEConfig.

Please read it completely from [Documentation](http://www.jasypt.org/webconfiguration.html)

Comment: Yes it will be different. Same applies to my application (a web application) restarts/redeploys. Shouldn't the encrypted string be same each time ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it.`JAsypt` offers several ways to do it. please read my updated answer.